# is there a OS dev framework that uses the menubar?

Tags: windows, macos, qt, cross-platform, wxwidgets

I am thinking in build an application that stays at the menubar in OSX and the clock in Windows.
I would like to know if any of the cross-platforms frameworks (like wxwidgets, qt etc) are able to help me accomplish this.
Or is this so OS specific that I would have to build one app for each?

[image: google drive for osx, an example of a "menubar application"]

thanks,
Joe

Comment: Why the hell did someone downvote it?? People are surely weird

Comment: Jonathan, probably because this question appears to be off-topic. From the [Help Centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

Comment: This is not OT at all, the question is factual and doesn't ask for any opinions. It's a pity it can't be answered now.

Comment: @VZ Agreed. A good answer to this question simply provides one or more frameworks, and references the relevant APIs from those frameworks. It is 100% factual.

Comment: I guess admins get more admpoints from blocking questions than helping answering them. I would like someone to unhold the question or tell me where I can ask for someone to unhold it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt can happily do this for you. See the [QSystemTrayIcon](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html#details) class, as well as it's [setContextMenu()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html#setContextMenu) function.